# OpenCV (Java binding) Use CvSVM in HoGDescriptor - How to convert it?

Tags: java, opencv, svm

i've already figured out how to train a CvSVM using the OpenCV Java bindings. I thought i could use this for the HOGDescriptor like this

`CvSVM svm = new CvSVM();
svm.load("svm.xml");

HOGDescriptor hoG = new HOGDescriptor();
hoG.setSVMDetector(svm);`

I was pretty surprised to see that this doesn't work since setSVMDetector() has a Mat as an argument. It seems like a conversion is possible, as one can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15339657/training-custom-svm-to-use-with-hogdescriptor-in-opencv). My problem is that i couldn't figure out how this conversion could be done in Java up to now, since i don't know how i convert this

```
const CvSVMDecisionFunc* df = decision_func;
```

to Java code.

So i have two questions:

1. Could anybody give me some help to get the conversion done?
2. Is there a better way to use a SVM in OpenCV for a HoGDescriptor / detector?

Any help would be nice!

Thanks in advance,

Nils