# HoG+SVM -> HOGDescriptor::setsvmdetector

Tags: c++, svm

I want to feed the `HOGDescriptor` (CPU interface) with a trained SVM. The HOG Descriptor offers a method `setSVMDetector(const vector<float>& detector)` and I'm asking what has to be in `vector<float>& detector`?

I have a trained SVM which can create a xml file. I want to use `hog.setSVMdetector(const vector<float>& detector)` for the custom dataset. How to use this function for our own data? Kindly anyone suggest the solution.

I am using MS VS to execute the code.

Answer (score 0):

This **detector (or a set of coefficients)** has to be computed from your trained model (XML file). This XML file contains all the information about your model/classifier (most importantly **support vectors**). These coefficients are computed from the support vectors. If you are using OpenCV SVM, then you can use [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15339657/training-custom-svm-to-use-with-hogdescriptor-in-opencv) (check the answer) for computing **detector** which you can directly use to customize your HOG detector.

Few things to note: in their answer, they are calling **detector (or set of coefficients)** as **support_vector**. But they are the same thing. Also, use your class labels as +1 (positive) and -1 (negative). Otherwise you might get incorrect detections.