# Different results from OpenCV in Python and C++ implementations for HOG object detection

Tags: python, c++, opencv, computer-vision, object-detection

I have implemented HOG face detector in Python and C++ using OpenCV. I tried to keep the code in both the implementations quite the same. However, I am getting different results in both. In Python, it works correctly, however, in C++ it is showing completely incorrect results. Below is an example of their outputs (first one in Python and second one in C++): 
[image]
[image]

First, I trained an OpenCV linear SVM classifier for both the implementations and saved them in XML files (model files). Then, I extracted the coefficients (which are used for customizing a HOG detector during the testing process) from the models (XML files) using [this code](http://answers.opencv.org/question/56655/how-to-use-a-custom-svm-with-hogdescriptor-in-python/) for Python implementation and [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15339657/training-custom-svm-to-use-with-hogdescriptor-in-opencv?rq=1) for C++ implementation. That is, these coefficients are going to be the inputs for the function **setSVMDetector(const std::vector< float > input_coefficients)** during testing process.

Ideally, these coefficients should be the same since they are computed from the same dataset and using OpenCV. I have checked manually these coefficients values by saving them in the text files for both the implementations and found that they are nearly the same. So, I would expect my future customized HOG detector should work nearly the same in both the implementations.

Below are the test codes for detecting a face in a test image using both implementations.

Python implementation:

```
import cv2
im = cv2.imread("..\\test_imgs\\1.png", 0) # test image
hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor((96, 128), (16,16), (8,8), (8,8), 9)

coeffs = pickle.load(open("coeffs_from_model")) # load coeffs already computed from model
hog.setSVMDetector( np.array(coeffs)) # customize HOG detector

found, w = hog.detectMultiScale(im,  winStride=(8,8), padding=(32,32), scale=4.05)
draw_detections(im, found_filtered) # method for drawing BBs on image
```

C++ implementation:

```
cv::Mat im = cv::imread("..\\test_imgs\\1.png", 0);
cv::HOGDescriptor hog(cv::Size(96, 128), cv::Size(16, 16), cv::Size(8, 8), cv::Size(8, 8), 9);

LinearSVM svm; // check the link 
svm.load(model.c_str());

std::vector<float> coeffs;
svm.getSupportVector(coeffs); // compute coeffs from model

hog.setSVMDetector(coeffs); // customize HOG detector

std::vector<cv::Rect> found; // holds the detected BBs
hog.detectMultiScale(im, found, 0, cv::Size(8, 8), cv::Size(32, 32), 4.05); 
drawLocations(im, found, cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0)); // method for drawing BBs on the image.
```

In order to check if the coefficients computed for the C++ are incorrect. I used them in the Python implementation and interestingly, they work quite the same. So, now I am not getting why the HOG object in the C++ implementation is not working correctly despite having the correct coefficients.

I have used the same initialization of the HOG object in C++ as I did for Python and keep the code nearly the same in both implementations since they both use the same OpenCV.

Comment: Can you demonstrate that your *Python* `coeffs = pickle.load(open("coeffs_from_model"))` is doing exactly what your *C++* `std::vector<float> coeffs;
svm.getSupportVector(coeffs);` is doing?

Comment: @boardrider: I used the coefficients computed in the C++ implementation, in the Python testing code. And, there it worked completely correct. I also did the other way round, i.e., using the coefficients computed in Python (which is already working) in C++ testing code. However, it showed almost the same error as it is showing with its own coefficients (C++ ones). From this, I concluded two things: (i) coefficients are correct (either Python or C++) and (ii) There is something wrong in the C++ implementation, which I am still struggling to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the answer now. Both code written above is correct. Problem lies on the labels used for the training. I was using "0" (face class) and "1" (non-face class) as the labels in both implementations.

For Python implementation, this labellings are working correctly, however, for C++ implementation, it seems like it has to be "+1" (face class) and "-1" (non-face class) as I found it [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/ml/introduction_to_svm/introduction_to_svm.html). In that example, at the end of the source code, **labels** are provided as:

```
// Set up training data
float labels[4] = {1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0};
Mat labelsMat(4, 1, CV_32FC1, labels);
```